# how to use multiple updatepanels in same aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, triggers, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a registration wizard page and some dropdownlists are used. I have added scriptmanager and I have used update panels for this.But only first updatepanel works properly and i cannot take selected values from dropdownlists in other update panels. When i insert these dropdownlists into the first update panel, i can take values of these dropdownlists. Why this happen ? What can i do for this?

My first update panel that works properly:

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
          <div class="control-group">
               <label for="Il" class="control-label">İl</label>
               <div class="controls">
                 <asp:DropDownList class="ui-wizard-content" runat="server" name="City" ID="ddlCity" data-rule-required="true" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="İl Seçiniz" Value="" />                                                        
                 </asp:DropDownList>
               </div>
         </div>
         <div class="control-group">
            <label for="Ilce" class="control-label">İlçe</label>
               <div class="controls">
                  <asp:DropDownList class="ui-wizard-content" runat="server" name="District" ID="ddlDistrict" data-rule-required="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                       <asp:ListItem Text="İlçe Seçiniz" Value="" />
                  </asp:DropDownList>
               </div>
         </div>
       </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCity" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
         </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My all aspx page:

```
<body>  
    <div class="container-fluid" id="content">
        <div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span8">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-title">
            <h3>
                <i class="icon-magic"></i>
                Bireysel Müşteri Hesap Açma Formu
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box-content">
            <form runat="server" novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal form-wizard ui-formwizard" id="Form1">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
                </asp:ScriptManager>

                <div style="display: block;" class="step ui-formwizard-content" id="Div3"...>...</div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="step ui-formwizard-content" id="Div4">
                    <ul class="wizard-steps steps-4">...</ul>
                    <div class="step-forms">
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="Il" class="control-label">İl</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <asp:DropDownList class="ui-wizard-content" runat="server" name="City" ID="ddlCity" data-rule-required="true" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="İl Seçiniz" Value="" />                                                        
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="Ilce" class="control-label">İlçe</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <asp:DropDownList class="ui-wizard-content" runat="server" name="District" ID="ddlDistrict" data-rule-required="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="İlçe Seçiniz" Value="" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCity" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel> 

                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="display: none;" class="step ui-formwizard-content" id="Div5">
                    <ul class="wizard-steps steps-4">...</ul>
                    <div class="step-forms">
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>

                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlHizmetSecimi" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"/>
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="HizmetSecimi" class="control-label">Hizmet Seçimi</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <asp:DropDownList class="ui-wizard-content" name="HizmetSecimi" runat="server" ID="ddlHizmetSecimi" data-rule-required="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlHizmetSecimi_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Lütfen Seçiniz" Value="" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label for="TarifeSecimi" class="control-label">Tarife Seçimi</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <asp:DropDownList class="ui-wizard-content" runat="server" name="TarifeSecimi" ID="ddlTarifeSecimi" data-rule-required="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Enabled="false">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Lütfen Seçiniz" Value="" /> 
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <asp:Label for="PaketSecimi" Visible="false" id="lblPaket"  class="control-label" runat="server" Text="Paket Seçimi"></asp:Label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <asp:DropDownList class="ui-wizard-content" runat="server" name="PaketSecimi" ID="ddlPaketSecimi" data-rule-required="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" sty Visible="false">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Seçiniz" Value="" />
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                    <div class="control-group">...</div>


                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">...</asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    <div class="control-group">...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div style="display: none;" class="step ui-formwizard-content" id="fourthstep"...>...</div>
                <div class="form-actions">...</div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: For instance: In code-behind, ddlTarifeSecimi.SelectedValue returns "". This cannot take selected value from the related dropdownlist.

Comment: Perhaps you are not setting the AutoPostBack property.. also use JavaScript if you set the AutoPostBack = false it's fairly straight forward

Comment: @DJKRAZE Can you give an example, please? Where can i set the AutoPostBack property?

Answer (score 0):

set autopostback property of each dropdownlist to be true

as

```
    AutoPostBack="true"
```

you have used it only for first dropdownlist do the same for others.

```
<asp:DropDownList class="ui-wizard-content" name="HizmetSecimi" runat="server" ID="ddlHizmetSecimi" data-rule-required="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlHizmetSecimi_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Lütfen Seçiniz" Value="" />
 </asp:DropDownList>
```